# How to label clusters of rows based on matches using True/False?

Tags: r, matching

Using this R function I am able to see the matching ratio for row clusters:

```
# Matching ratio function
match_ratio <- function(x)
  cbind(x, match_ratio = rowMeans(mapply(`==`, x[1, -1], x[, -1])))
```

I would like to also label each cell value as True if they match in the row clusters and False if they do not.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Sample input is

```
ID  Var1  Var2
1   East  Juice
1   East  Soda
2   West  Apple
2   East  Apple
```

Sample Output would be

```
ID  Var1   Var2
1   True   False
1   True   False
2   False  True
2   False  True
```

So the clusters are based in ID.  1 is a cluster as is 2.

Comment: What row clusters are you talking about? You should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Comment: Please see edit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a `dplyr` method:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_all(funs(n_distinct(.) == 1))

     ID  Var1  Var2
  <int> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1  TRUE FALSE
2     1  TRUE FALSE
3     2 FALSE  TRUE
4     2 FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly.  Is there also away to do partial matches?  Say if the cells being compared shared 80% of the letters.  Thanks again.

Comment: the strategy for that depends on what your "fuzzy" matches are. It's likely easier to do this type of data "cleaning" before you get to the tabulating steps